# Convert django/python dict via json to javascript dict

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am trying to convert a python dict to a Javascript dict. As far as I understood I have to convert the python dict to Json, which I can convert to a Javascript Object

view.py

```
jsonheaderdict = json.dumps ( headerdict)
```

`{{jsonheaderdict}}` in template results in

```
 {"F 1": ["BBBB", "AAAAA"], "F 2": ["ASDASD"], "F 3": ["QWEQWE"]}
```

and my js looks like this

```
$(".dict").click(function () {
  alert("first alert");
  var result = JSON.parse(jsonheaderdict);
  alert(result);
});
```

The first alert shows, the second one doesn't. What am i missing? Already tried `var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonheaderdict);` which didnt work either.
I searched for similar question but didnt find any soultion that worked for me.

**EDIT**
For a better understanding how `jsonheaderdict` is created in my view:

```
headerdict = dict()
for d in projectdescriptors:                     #list of objects called descriptors
    dp = projectprojections.filter(descriptor=d) #list of objects connected to descriptors 
    parray = []
    for p in dp:
        parray.append(p.name)
    headerdict[d.name] = parray
```

Comment: do you want to `alert` all three entries ? what should the `second alert` show ?

Comment: The alert is just verify that the conversion works. Ultimately I wnat to use the dict to create a tableheader with 2 rows, where the dict:key column has the same lenght as all the corresponding dict:value columns together.

Answer (score 1):

**@Rubik**, I may guess, **alert()** takes a string as parameter and you're passing it an object in second call to alert().

> **JSON.parse()** creates an object from the string representation of any object (array, set etc.).

Please try to change your **JS** code as follows (just modify 2 lines):

> Please comment if it doesn't work, I will update my answer to help you.

```
$(".dict").click(function () {
  alert("first alert");
  // var result = JSON.parse(jsonheaderdict);
  alert(JSON.stringify(jsonheaderdict));
});
```

» Try below sample code for verification.

```js
var jsonheaderdict = {"F 1": ["BBBB", "AAAAA"], "F 2": ["ASDASD"], "F 3": ["QWEQWE"]};

console.log(jsonheaderdict); 

alert(jsonheaderdict)

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonheaderdict))
```

Comment: Instead of alert, he/she should use console.log instead.

Comment: Correct, that's also okay, so in this case, he/she can display object on browser's console. **console.log()** takes any kind of objects as parameter.

Comment: `alert("{{jsonheaderdict}}");` results in an alert saying _{{jsonheaderdict}}_. consol.log(jsonheaderdict) results in `{F 1: Array(2), F 2: Array(1), F 3: Array(1), asd: Array(1)}
F 1
:
(2) ["BBBB", "AAAAA"]
F 2
:
["ASDASD"]
F 3
:
["QWEQWE"]
asd
:
["111"]
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: **@Rubik**, try `alert(JSON.stringify(jsonheaderdict));` and let me know if it works. It should work according to the result of `console.log(jsonheaderdict)`.

Comment: It shows `[object Object]`. I managed to make everything work using a dictionariy and a list. It is different than i thought it would work but its actualy quite nice. Still, thanks for your effort.

Comment: No problem **@Rubik**, I have updated my answer, check it again. Use `alert(JSON.stringify(jsonheaderdict));`.

Comment: I have added **Code snippet**, try it. Now it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to recognize that you are not passing a value from Python to JavaScript, you are *writing JavaScript source code using Python*.

This…

> ```
> jsonheaderdict = {"F 1": ["BBBB", "AAAAA"], "F 2": ["ASDASD"], "F 3": ["QWEQWE"]}
> ```

… is the JavaScript syntax to assign an object (created with an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)) to `jsonheaderdict`.

It isn't JSON. It isn't a string. It makes no sense to put it anywhere near `JSON.parse`.

Just use the object directly.

Further reading: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I get the "Theres no such thinkg as a JSON Object" part, but I'm not sure about this not beeing a a Json str, since [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) says **json.dumps(obj,[...]): Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str[...]**.

Comment: @Rubick — And at *that moment* it is a string of JSON. **Then** you write it into JavaScript source code and it stops being a string and it stops being JSON.

Comment: Okay. But as far as I understood `JSON.parse` is the attempt to create a JS dictionary from the given JSON?

Comment: From a string of JSON which, as I have pointed out twice already, `jsonheaderdict` is not. (And the term is "object" not "dictionary")